# Error when saving Fortran source in Atom

Tags: fortran, atom-editor

Whenever I save a file in the `atom` text editor using the `Fortran - Modern` language, I get the following errors:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfhK3.jpg]

What is the sources of these errors?

Comment: It is good to enter at least some of the errors as text. Thy should be possible to find by text search.

Comment: Hi, I think you are modifying this code (about density-matrix propagation) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831681/fortran-for-a-beginner Here, this original code is written in so-called "free-form" source, while your file name is given the suffix ".f", which is often interpreted by compilers as "fixed-form" source (where all the statements need to begin with the 7th column, except for labels and continuation symbol). Is is possible for you to change the file suffix to ".f90", so that the file will be regarded as free-form (no such restriction on the column)?