# Errors Typing Fortran Language in Atom Text Editor

Tags: fortran, atom-editor

Whenever I type on the `atom` texteditor using the `Fortran - Modern` language, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing file 

'C:\cygwin64\home\opensystemdynamicsnew2 (with notes).f'

Script failed`
```

Whenever I save a file, I get the error:

```
Error: spawn gfortran ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please read the description of tags you add. Tag [tag:atom] is not about any editor.

Comment: It is suspicious that you use something called "Fortran -Modern" and a `.f` suffix.  `.f` is commonly used for old fixed form source files. Also the parentheses in the file name could be problematic, but hopefully not.

Comment: @VladimirF Which suffix should I be using for the file then? I recently download `Fortran` from `CygWin` so I assume I have the latest version.

Comment: This is very similar to a recently posted [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944783/error-when-saving-fortran-source-in-atom)

Comment: Indeed, the errors in the image made me forget what they were about. @J123 If the previous question is yours, you should probably delete it and keep just one.

Comment: @J123 Try `.f90` or if you have your `.f` files try some other choice of Fortran, not Modern.